Tomcat Login Failed-Tomcat docker
I have created a tomcat container with tomcat image. I added the users as  and <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui","manager-gui","manager-script"/> in conf---tomcat-users.xml but when i am accessing the browser with url ip:8080/manager/html it prompt for username and password but it still not logged in

roles is an XML attribute, the correct format is e.g. roles="tomcat,role1", give it a try
